# How to correctly use socket close for fork?

Tags: c, sockets, fork

I have questions about how to correctly close the socket file descriptor. Let's assume the server forks another procedure whenever it accepts a new connection. The original socket file descriptor is `sockfd` and the new socket file descriptor is `new_sockfd`.

```
sockfd = socket(...)
bind(...);
listen(...);

while(1) {
  new_sockfd = accept(...);
  if(fork() == 0) {
    // Child process
    dosomething(...);

  }
  else {

  }
}
```

My question is, where we should put `close(sockfd)` and `close(new_sockfd)`. I have seen some examples in the website (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_quick_guide.htm  "Handle Multiple Connection") they put `close(sockfd)` inside the `if` block and `close(new_sockfd)` in the `else` block. But, after the fork, aren't the two processes running in parallel? If parent process closes the `new_sockfd`, won't it affect the child process to handle the socket? Also, if child process executes `close(sockfd)`, won't this affect the entire socket program?

Comment: @JosephMyers That is not correct. The file descriptor is distinct in both processes. The parent should close the accepted socket: it remains open in the child process.

Comment: @EJP I'm going to look into this some more and perhaps get back with details. I'm more familiar with BSD systems which in my experience programming servers and shells and forking processes in general gave more fine-grained control over whether file descriptors and associated resources were duplicated or shared. Thanks for taking the time to comment and prompting me to revisit what I remembered from experience.

Comment: Isn't the code inside the if actually Parent process (you wrote Child process in the comment?) . The parent's call to fork returns the child's pid (and enters the condition), the child's call to fork returns nil. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274764/what-does-exit-do-in-this-ruby-if-fork-block

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a process forks, file descriptors are duplicated in the child process.  However, these file descriptors are distinct from each other.  Closing a file descriptor in the child doesn't affect the corresponding file descriptor in the parent, and vice versa.

In your case, since the child process needs the accepted socket `new_sockfd` and the parent process continues to use the listening socket `sockfd`, the child should `close(sockfd)` (in your `if` block; this doesn't affect the parent) and the parent should `close(new_sockfd)` (in your `else` block; this doesn't affect the child).  The fact that the parent and child are running at the same time doesn't affect this.

Comment: Oh! Now I totally understand this concept. Thank you dbush :)

Comment: @Jes No problem.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The parent should close the accepted socket (in the `else` block): it remains open in the child process until the child is done with it, at which point it should issue its own close.

Comment: Like the parent closes the accepted socket, the child wants to close the listening one.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for your kind reply. I am still a bit confused, is it because fork will also duplicate another new socket connection so we have to close each file descriptor twice? I am not quite sure why "it remains open in the child process until the child is done with it", since the two processes (parent and child) run in parallel and the new_sockfd might be closed by parent process before child process uses that, right?

Comment: @alk It is better to create the listening with ``SOCK_CLOEXEC`` if possible.

Comment: Sig. The FDs are distinct. The parent closes *its* socket *descriptor*, but the *socket* remains open until the *child* closes *its* descriptor*. Or the other way round in the case of the listening socket as per @alk's comment. And exactly as re-stated in dbush's subsequent answer.