# what does exit do in this ruby if fork block

Tags: ruby

some code like following:

```
def start
    if fork 
        do something
        exit 0
    end
end
```

fork duplicate a child process,am i right?
But my question is which process does `exit 0` really exit?the parent process or child process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fork`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Process.html#method-c-fork), if given no block, has two different returns. To the parent it returns the process id (PID) of the child. To the child it returns `nil` which is false.

This is taken advantage of like so:

```
if fork
    ...this is the parent...
else
    ...this is the child...
end
```

So your code above forks, the parent does something, then the parent exits and the child lives on.